# Meraki MX84 VPN question

Tags: meraki

I'm looking to replace our Cisco 2900 router, and one of the choices is the MX84.  My question is that can I use the AnyConnect VPN client for the MX84 or do I need a Cisco ASA?

Comment: I removed the question for opinion based answers to make the question on topic here.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Meraki MX routers [do not](https://community.meraki.com/t5/Security-SD-WAN/What-VPN-Clients-are-Meraki-users-using/td-p/17936) support Cisco Anyconnect.  If Anyconnect is a requirement I'm afraid you'll have to stick with Cisco branded routers.

Answer (score 1):

**No**t currently supported.

This is likely due to the fact that AnyConnect establishes an IPSec Tunnel based on IKE v2 whereas the MX appliance (afaik) still uses IKE v1 for negotation.